# How does a C++ compiler expand prefix and postfix operator++()?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, prefix, postfix-operator

Consider:

```
class Example
{
private:
    int m_i;

public:
    Example(int i) : m_i{i} {}

    //Post-fix
    Example operator++(int) {m_i++; return *this;}

    //Pre-fix
    Example& operator++() {m_i++; return *this;}

    void print() const {std::cout << m_i << '\n'}
};
```

I was experimenting with this to determine how the compiler expanded a call to the prefix and postfix operators.

For example, when I write something like this:

```
Example e = 1;
e++;
```

I expected it to expand to something like "e.operator++(int)", or taking it a step further, I expected

```
e++(2);
```

to expand to something like "e.operator++(2).", but what I get instead is the compiler complaining about some "no match for call to '(Example) (int)'".

Next I was curious as to how "++e" mysteriously expanded into "e.operator++()", i.e. the one that returns a reference.

Playing around some more, I ended up with:

```
Example e = 1;
++e++;
e.print();
```

Which printed 2, and then:

```
Example e = 1;
(++e)++;
e.print();
```

Which printed 3.

I understand that (++e) returns a reference to the object which is then post-incremented by one, so this makes sense. I also suspect that "++e++" is giving the postfix operator precedence here (as I read in another post), so this is incrementing the temporary variable returned by the postfix operator. This too makes sense. This led me to wonder about how expressions like

```
++++e
++e++++
++++e++
++++e++++
```

are expanded (they all compile and run with expected results).

So really, what the hell is going on on the inside and how does the compiler know which operator++() to call, and how are these expressions expanded (especially in the prefix case)? What is the purpose of the placeholder variable in "operator++(int)"?

Comment: The placeholder is only there to allow the two operators to be distinct during overload resolution. The argument is unspecified and must remain unused.

Comment: Read the above link, all of your contrived examples at the end lack sequence points.

Comment: To make your postfix operator behave semantically as expected, change it to: `Example operator++(int) { return Example(m_i++); }`

Comment: reopened; there's no undefined behaviour here, and I think generic "operator overloading" thread is not a good answer to this question

Comment: @CoryKramer there's a sequence point on entry and exit of each function (using pre-C++11 terminology); and overloaded operators are functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the purpose of the placeholder variable in "operator++(int)"?

Because the `++` operator has two distinct functions: postfix-++ and prefix-++.  Therefore, when overloading it, there must be two different function signatures.

> how does the compiler know which operator++() to call,

When your code uses prefix-`++` (for example: `++e;`), the function with signature `operator++()` is called.  When your code uses postfix-`++` (for example: `e++`;) , the function with signature `operator++(int)` is called, and the compiler will supply an unspecified dummy argument value.

Technically, the implementation of `operator++(int)` could use the dummy argument value. And you could pass your own value by writing `e.operator++(5);` instead of `e++;`.  But this would be considered bad coding style -- when overloading operators, it's recommended to retain the semantics of the built-in operators to avoid confusing people reading the code.

Note that your current implementation of postfix-`++` does not respect this rule: the normal semantic is that the previous value should be returned; but your code returns the updated value.

> `++e++++;`

For parsing this statement you need to know about these parsing rules:

- Tokens are parsed by "maximal munch", i.e. this means `++ e ++ ++;`  (and not some unary-`+` operators).
- The language grammar determines from these tokens which expressions are the operand of which operators. This process can be summarised in a [precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Consulting the table for that expression tells you:  `++(((e++)++))`.  Using the expansion I mentioned earlier, this can be written in function call notation:

```
((e.operator++(0)).operator++(0)).operator++();
```

These functions need to be called left-to-right in this case, because a member function cannot be entered before the expression it's being called on has been evaluated.

So, supposing we had `Example e(1);` before this statement, the following function calls occur in this order:

- `e.operator++(int)` - sets `e.m_i` to `2` and returns a temporary (I'll call it `temp1` as pseudocode) with `temp1.m_i` as `2`.
- `temp1.operator++(int)` - sets `temp1.m_i` to `3`, and returns `temp2` whose `m.i` is `3`
- `temp2.operator++()` - sets `temp2.m_i` to `4` and returns a reference to `temp2`.

---

NB. My answer only talks about the overloaded operator being a member function. It's also possible to overload `++` (both forms) as a non-member. In that case, the behaviour would be unchanged from my description, but the "written in function call notation" expression would take different syntax.

Comment: So what about the expansion of something like "++++e++"? I'll assume I wasn't wrong about my assumption that postfix has precedence which would mean that the compiler sees something (rather roughly) equivalent to (++(++(e++))). Is this correct? Expanding this to actual function calls, would it be e.operator++(int).operator++().operator()++?